# How can I align two forms below each other?

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to create a Login-form in HTML inside my C# project.
This is my current result:

[image: Image showing mis-aligned controls]

But as you see it is quite ugly but I just cant align them in a way that they are pretty. My favorite would be that "Registrieren" is above the "Username" field.

This is my current code put in a simple way. But if the complete code is necessary, just ask.

```
<div class="is-flex" style="justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:100%;">
     
   <form id="addGuestOrCompany"> 
         <div class="control">
             <div class="buttonWrapper">
                <button type="submit" id="registerButton" class="button buy">
                    Neu Registrieren
                </button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>

     <br />
     <br />
     <br />

     <form id="addGuest"> 
          <fieldset>
              <div class="field">
                 <label class="label subtitle has-text-white" for="userName">Username</label>
                 <input class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="userName" name="userName">
              </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="control">
              <div class="buttonWrapper">
                 <button type="submit" id="addGuestBtn" class="button buy">Enter</button>
              </div>
           </div>
     </form>

</div>
```

I use the Bulma IO-framework. I hope this is all the information you need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be great if you could create a snippet as we can't see what the CSS is doing.

Comment: Snippet? What do you mean by that? Sorry i really am an beginner

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/592958. This would at least give us something to look at. Without the CSS we're a little in the dark

Comment: Bulma IO-framework seems to use [css flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Maybe that links helps understanding the basics of it, not sure what your framework does with it, i don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading your provided source right, the parent  is set to

```
display: flex;
```

via its class "is-flex"?
If thats the case, the quickest solution I can think of would be adding

```
flex-direction: column;
```

to its style attribute.

Comment: Wow that was it! I searched so long for a solution and it was just so easy!:D thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark as accepted answer.